# I can get user details but I can't work out how to change them?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

So, I can get data and it all works but I can't seem to work out how to update it without updating everything, just what the user wants to update,

I came up with this 'update' method below but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
George.

**views.py**

```
class UserDetailsAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserDetailSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data['email']
        first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        phone_number = validated_data['phone_number']
        password = validated_data['password']
        user_obj = User(
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone_number=phone_number
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()

        return validated_data
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'phone_number',
            'is_active',
            'email_confirmed',
            'phone_number_confirmed',
            'date_joined',
            'last_login',
            'nick_name',
            'id'

        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, what you are trying to do is probably createOrUpdate, hence you better check if the User already exists.

Reference: Look at [UserDetail](https://github.com/addu390/app-inventor-backend/blob/master/coreModule/apiviews.py)
Notice the link `user = get_or_none(User, user_id=user_id)`, where I first check if the user is present to update particular fields (as seen in the dictionary `update_user`)